# Duplicate constructor warning in Delphi XE2

Tags: unit-testing, delphi

I have the following .dpr

```
program TPWDDBManager;
{

  Delphi DUnit Test Project
  -------------------------
  This project contains the DUnit test framework and the GUI/Console test runners.
  Add "CONSOLE_TESTRUNNER" to the conditional defines entry in the project options
  to use the console test runner.  Otherwise the GUI test runner will be used by
  default.

}

{$IFDEF CONSOLE_TESTRUNNER}
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}

uses
  DUnitTestRunner,
  TestuTPWDDBManager in 'TestuTPWDDBManager.pas';

{$R *.RES}

begin
  DUnitTestRunner.RunRegisteredTests;
end.
```

and the following unit:

```
unit TestuTPWDDBManager;
{

  Delphi DUnit Test Case
  ----------------------
  This unit contains a skeleton test case class generated by the Test Case Wizard.
  Modify the generated code to correctly setup and call the methods from the unit
  being tested.

}

interface

uses TestFramework;

type
  // Test methods for class TPWDDBManager

  TestTPWDDBManager = class(TTestCase)
  strict private
  public
    procedure SetUp; override;
    procedure TearDown; override;
  published
    procedure TestUpdateVersion;
    procedure TestGetPWD;
    procedure TestChangePWD;
    procedure TestReset;
    procedure TestIsReset;

  end;

  Idlg = interface(IInvokable)
    ['{E369D075-E3CA-4BB3-896C-0D623DE5798F}']

  end;

implementation

uses SysUtils,Delphi.Mocks;

procedure TestTPWDDBManager.SetUp;
var
  FMessageDLG : TMock<IDlg>;
begin
end;

procedure TestTPWDDBManager.TearDown;
begin
end;

procedure TestTPWDDBManager.TestGetPWD;
begin
  // TODO: Validate method results
end;

procedure TestTPWDDBManager.TestIsReset;
begin
end;

procedure TestTPWDDBManager.TestChangePWD;
begin
end;

procedure TestTPWDDBManager.TestReset;
begin
end;

procedure TestTPWDDBManager.TestUpdateVersion;
begin

end;

initialization
  // Register any test cases with the test runner
  RegisterTest(TestTPWDDBManager.Suite);
end.
```

When I compile I get several warnings like:

> [DCC Warning] W1029 Duplicate constructor 'TExpectation.CreateAfter'
>   with identical parameters will be inacessible from C++ [DCC Warning]
>   W1029 Duplicate constructor 'TExpectation.CreateAfterWhen' with
>   identical parameters will be inacessible from C++ [DCC Warning] W1029
>   Duplicate constructor 'TExpectation.CreateAtLeastOnce' with identical
>   parameters will be inacessible from C++

but if I remove the line `FMessageDLG : TMock<IDlg>;` then the warning disappears

any idea of how to solve this ?

Comment: Delphi Mocks and C++ Compatibility Compiler flag in delphi projects are mutually incompatible.  Just turn off the C++ Compatibility options in the Compiler settings.  Remember that Delphi is used for many purposes. This warning serves a purpose in some use scenarios, but not in most delphi user's daily routines.  You can disable the warning. `{$WARN UPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR OFF}`  <-- add to your unit

Comment: @WarrenP this should be an answer

Comment: @WarrenP: I guess `UPLICATE` is actually `DUPLICATE`, right? One question: putting this on my unit didn't solve, I had to put it on the project's unit and then the warning disappeared, why is that?

Comment: Project scope is first. Unit scope won't affect other units, thus the difference.

Comment: Can't seem to migrate or edit old comments. Posted as an answer anyways just in case more people see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning means exactly what it says. If you're not interested in C++ compatibility, then simply disable the warning. Anything else would require changing the definition of TExpectation to give it constructors that differ by parameter list instead of just by name.

Answer (score 7):

Delphi Mocks and C++ Compatibility Compiler flag in delphi projects are mutually incompatible. Just turn off the C++ Compatibility options in the Compiler settings. Remember that Delphi is used for many purposes. This warning serves a purpose in some use scenarios, but not in most delphi user's daily routines. You can disable the warning.

```
{$WARN DUPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR OFF}
```

Add to your PROJECT (.dpr) scope or unit scope, as needed to fix.

Comment: Hi. That directive is automatically removed by the IDE from DPK files. Any fix for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71725441/warn-duplicate-ctor-dtor-off-gets-deleted-from-dpk-file

Comment: @IceCold Where exactly within the DPK did you place this? FWIW, the IDE "owns" that unit. I have success putting this at the very top between the `unit` and `uses` sections.