# {$WARN DUPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR OFF} gets deleted from Dpk file

Tags: delphi, compiler-warnings, compiler-directives

I need to turn off this compiler warning because I don't intend to make my library compatible with C++.

If I put the compiler directive in the PAS file that generates the warning, it is ignored.

People on the mighty internet say that {$WARN DUPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR OFF} should be placed in the DPR file. It works. But if you put in in DPK files, the IDE will delete it every time I change the Project Options (we all know that at when changing the options, the DPK file gets partially rebuilt).

Question: How do I make the directive stay in the DPK file?

To reproduce it:

- Start Delphi 10.4,
- start a new Delphi package (File main menu)
- add {$WARN DUPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR OFF} after {$IMPLICITBUILD ON}.
- now open Project Options, change something and close the dialog. The directive will be gone.

Comment: Once more: add code as an example that allows others to reproduce what you experience , because by far not everything in a DPR is rewritten from scratch when it is saved.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Project>Options>Building>Delphi Compiler>Hints and Warnings, select the platform and configuration, then set that warning to `False`. And Save.  (Depending on your version of Delphi, the exact location of this setting might be different.)
[image: Screenshot of warning setting]

Comment: Why would it get deleted?  I always turn that one off in the options, and don't have a problem with the .dproj file getting deleted.

Comment: So what happens if the .dpr/.pas file gets deleted?  My point is that it needs to be saved _somewhere_, and that _somewhere_ could always get deleted somehow.
Yes, the IDE itself plays around with the .dpr file and sometimes messes things up, but the .dproj file seems pretty safe.

Comment: Hi Philip :) - Dproj is not a "mandatory" Delphi file. If you go on GitHub (or where ever on Internet) you will have many Delphi projects delivered without Dproj files. This is why (even though I agree with your solution) I would like to find a way to make the IDE keep the directive in the Dpk file.

Comment: Why would it get deleted?" - To clarify: I never said that the dproj file gets deleted by the IDE. I said that the {$WARN DUPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR OFF} text gets deleted from Dpk :)

Comment: PS: This is not really the answer that I was looking for. I need the directive in the DPK file, not in the DPROJ.
If someone else offers a better solution/answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In the following DPR file all these lines remain as-is in Delphi 7, even if IDE wise something is saved/changed/added:

```delphi
// My comment
{.$DEFINE MEMCHECK}
{$DEFINE BOMB}
// JCL_DEBUG_EXPERT_GENERATEJDBG ON
// JCL_DEBUG_EXPERT_INSERTJDBG ON
program pMain;

{$SetPEFlags $c20}
{.$define FullDebugMode}
{$I all.inc}

uses
  FastMM4,
  madExcept,
```

As you see I set a few compiler directives, while others are commented out (the leading dot makes it only a Pascal comment). Comments and empty lines also remain - nothing is rewritten there, especially not the directives. That's why I ask for a code example by you: you might use a position in your code other than these. Or a Delphi version which behaves differently.

**Even if** the IDE would rebuild your DPR from scratch you should be able to add a unit to your project that comes first, and in that you put your compiler directive. Compiler wise this must be encountered first then. But I have no clue why you don't do so and never will have a clue without code examples by you.

Comment: Hi. Sorry. My mistake! It only happens with DPK files. I got the impression that the bug appears also in the DPR but it does not. To reproduce it: Start Delphi 10.4, start a new Delphi package (File main menu) and add {$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
after {$IMPLICITBUILD ON}. Now open Project Options, change something and close the dialog. The IMPLICITBUILDING directive is gone.

Comment: Man! People are still using Delphi 7 today! I think Delphi 7 was the most glorious release :)